# -bash: R: command not found

Tags: r, osx-elcapitan

I often start an instance of R in my terminal just by entering "R".  Just not today.  I can open `R.app` using `open -a R` and open Rstudio using `open -a Rstudio`, and these work fine, but I'm failing at `R` and `R CMD BATCH ...` etc.  How can I start to diagnose this?

Comment: Ask your system administrator what's changed? This really sounds like a question for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) since you can't even get R to run.

Comment: @MrFlick, maybe you already got this, but make note that it DOES run in the context of Rstudio.

Comment: Have you upgraded your OS recently?

Comment: ...the reason I ask is because upon initially upgrading to El Capitan you may need to reinstall R, since the El Cap installer removes /usr/bin/R.

Comment: @joran, Yes, this appears to be coincident with starting to use El Capitan.

Comment: I would read [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011632.html) thread on r-sig-mac and also read about SIP in El Cap and consider whether you want to disable it.

Comment: @joran, sounds like you got to the heart of the matter.  Here's how to disable: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11